# Android Textview text cut off at bottom

Tags: java, android, textview

So I have 2 textviews, one above the other, but when the second text view is populated the cut is cut off at the bottom. The textview, titled header_subtitle has the issue in question

Clearly Im missing something obvious, but dont know what.
[[Issue][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVWYH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVWYH.png)

Here is the code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/search_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_results"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/product_results_header_height"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="?marginNormal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <FeatureTextView
                        android:id="@+id/header_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:textAppearance="?taTitleXL" />

                    <FeatureTextView
                        android:id="@+id/header_subtitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:layout_gravity="fill"
                        android:textAppearance="?taTitleXL"
                        android:padding="1sp"
                        android:visibility="gone"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/sort_spinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="?marginNormal" />

                <FeatureButton
                    android:id="@+id/refine_btn"
                    style="?buttonTertiary"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="?marginNormal"
                    android:text="@string/product_results_refine" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <SimpleFlowLayout
                android:id="@+id/category_links"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="?marginSmall"
                android:horizontalSpacing="?marginTiny"
                android:maxLines="2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/divider_horizontal"
            layout="@layout/divider_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_size"
            android:layout_below="@+id/container_header" />

        <FeatureTextView
            android:id="@+id/browse_no_results"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="?marginNormal"
            android:text="@string/product_results_no_results"
            android:textAppearance="?taTitleM"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/product_grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider_horizontal"
            android:numColumns="@integer/product_grid_cols"
            android:overScrollMode="@null"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/progress_footer"
            layout="@layout/loading"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/progress_view_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/progress_view_height"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <NoFilteredResultsView
            android:id="@+id/noFilteredResults"
            android:layout_below="@id/divider_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/coach_mark"
            layout="@layout/view_coach_mark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/coach_mark_margin_end"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/coach_mark_margin_top" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what textview is cut off, and if possible provide a screenshot? Also, be careful with that nested layouts, probably you can have less levels in that layout hierarchy (just a performance and readability tip)

Comment: which textview is it?  It looks like your layout isn't big enough.

Comment: Ah sorry, it is the header_subtitle

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One of your `LinearLayouts` has height set to `fill_parent`. change it to `wrap_content`.

Also, remove the `min_height` attribute. `Yout` have two text fields in there, so it looks like you're totally OK with the second getting cut off.

It's kind of hard to tell what you're going for, but see if that helps.

Comment: Not is correct if you have "weight" with long text, you will see cut text :)

Comment: In my case, TextView was set to "match_parent", when i changed it to "wrap_content" it worked

Answer (score 0):

i know it's so late, but this is work like charm for me. add this code to your textview

android:ellipsize="marquee" 
android:layout_weight="1"

Answer (score 0):

Merging two `TextView` tags into one solved my issue:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/app_version"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:text="© 1997 - 2020 "
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/text_digicollect"
            android:text="Onetime"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Changing to:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/app_version"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:text="© 1997 - 2020 OneTime"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```